# Why does this code print the fibonacci series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, do-while

So my question is about the line "`a, b=b, a+b`" as well as the line "`a,b = 0,1`"

What do these lines mean, what are they doing?

```
def fib2(n):
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        result.append(a)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

`a, b=b, a+b` is a **multiple assignment** statement. In such a statement expressions on the right-hand side are all evaluated
first before any of the assignments take place. The right-hand side expressions are evaluated from the left to the right.

Similar is the case for `a,b=0,1`, where `a` gets `0` and `b` gets `1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
a, b=b, a+b   # is described as

temp = a
a = b
b= temp + b
```

and if you look at `a,b = 0,1` in shell

```
In [37]: a,b = 0,1

In [38]: a,b
Out[38]: (0, 1)

In [40]: type((a, b))
Out[40]: tuple

In [41]: a
Out[41]: 0

In [42]: b
Out[42]: 1
```

so it just assignment of variables to the tuple values